# Opentok connection quality is null

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I am trying to get the connection quality of the video call in real time, but the session object returns the null quality.
How can I get the quality of the connection in real time?

```
let session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionID);

console.log(session) // return Object where connection is null
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Manik here from the Vonage Video API Team.

To look at quality data during the session, I recommend using the `getStats` APIs for both Publishers and Subscribers.

- [Publisher getStats](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#getStats)
- [Subscrbier getStats](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#getStats)